# How to perform a left join in SQLALchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a SQL query which perfroms a series of left joins on a few tables:

```
SELECT
<some attributes>
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
      ON attr = 1 AND attr2 = 1
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
    ON t1.Code = t2.Code AND t3.Date_ = t1.Date_
LEFT JOIN tabl4 t4
    ON t4.Code = t1.code AND t4.Date_ = t1.Date_
```

So far, I have:

```
(sa.select([idc.c.Code])
            .select_from(
                t1.join(t2, and_(t1.c.attr == 1, t2.c.attr2 = 1))
                .join(t3, t3.c.Code == t1.c.Code)))
```

but I can't figure out how to make the join a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You can use `outerjoin` in place of `join`

Comment: outerjoin is not a replacement for join. I need a left join.

Comment: @user1742188 The naming is confusing, but `outerjoin` performs a `left outer join` which is a synonym for `left join`.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The `isouter=True` flag will produce a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which is the same as a `LEFT JOIN`.

With your code:

```
(sa.select([idc.c.Code])
        .select_from(
            t1.join(t2, and_(t1.c.attr == 1, t2.c.attr2 = 1))
            .join(t3, t3.c.Code == t1.c.Code, isouter=True)))
```

Declarative example:

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
session.query(Model).join(AnotherModel, AnotherModel.model_id == Model.id, isouter=True)
```

Comment: I used the second solution(Declarative example), and works like a charm, love it!

Answer (score 11):

**Option 1 - LEFT JOIN and select ALL columns from both tables**

```
# Query the db
results = db.session.query(Table_1, Table_2).join(
      Table_2, Table_2.column_name == Table_1.column_name, 
      isouter=True).all()
# Iterate results and do stuff
for result in results:
    try:
        # Use [0] for accesing table_1 columns (left table) and use [1] for accesing table_2 columns (right table)
        print(result[0].column_name_x)
        print(result[0].column_name_y)
        print(result[1].column_name_x)
        print(result[1].column_name_y)
     except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

**Option 2 - LEFT JOIN and select SOME columns from both tables**

```
# Query the db
results = db.session.query(Table_1.column_name_x, Table_1.column_name_y Table_2.column_name_z).join(Table_2, Table_2.column_name == Table_1.column_name, isouter=True).all()
# Iterate results and do stuff
for result in results:
    try:
        # Use dot notation for accesing column from any table
        print(result.column_name_x)
        print(result.column_name_y)
        print(result.column_name_z)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: Option 3 - LEFT JOIN and select only SOME columns from right table


`db.query(RightTable.column).select_from(LeftTable).join(RightTable, LeftTable.column=RightTable.column, isouter=True).filter(condition).all()`

Answer (score 10):

Here is how to use isouter:

```
select_from(db.join(Table1, Table2, isouter=True).join(Table3, isouter=True))
```