# sqlalchemy query returning different result from direct psql query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I used to run my queries from a `dbshell` but then decided to integrate my workflow using SQLAlchemy inside Jupyter.
I discovered a discrepancy between the output of a query in the dbshell and SQLAlchemy and I can't figure out why.

First a summary of the schema I'm dealing with:

TABLE_1
~ id
~ oferta_id

TABLE_2
~ audience_id
~ member_id
~ order

TABLE_3
~ user_id

TABLE_4
~ member_id
~ joboffer_id
~ send_4_approval

The SQL query looks like this

```
select 
T1.id, T1.oferta_id, T2.order, T2.member_id, T4.joboffer_id, T4.send_4_approval from TABLE_1 T1 
left join TABLE_2 T2 on T1.id=T2.audience_id 
left join TABLE_3 T3 on T2.member_id=T3.user_id 
left join TABLE_4 T4 on T3.user_id=T4.member_id 
where T1.oferta_id = 3768 
order by T2.order;
```

The first rows of output of the query run in the dbshell are shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Note that this query correctly returns even the top rows where there is no entry in the last two selected columns.

I then tried performing the same query directly from Python 3 environment, using SQLAlchemy.
Below the script I'm using

```
engine = sa.create_engine(CLONE_DB_URL)

connection = engine.connect()
meta = sa.MetaData(connection)

# get necessary tables from remote database
TABLE_1 = sa.Table("TABLE_1", meta, autoload_with=engine)
TABLE_2 = sa.Table("TABLE_2", meta, autoload_with=engine)
TABLE_3 = sa.Table("TABLE_3", meta, autoload_with=engine)
TABLE_4 = sa.Table("TABLE_4", meta, autoload_with=engine)

# central database object by joining the tables
join_object = TABLE_1.join(
    TABLE_2,
    onclause=TABLE_1.c.id==TABLE_2.c.audience_id
).join(
    TABLE_3,
    onclause=TABLE_2.c.member_id==TABLE_3.c.user_id
).join(
    TABLE_4,
    onclause=TABLE_3.c.user_id==TABLE_4.c.member_id
)

# central SELECT statement
select_statement = sa.select(
    [
        TABLE_1.c.id,
        TABLE_1.c.oferta_id,
        TABLE_2.c.order,
        TABLE_2.c.member_id,
        TABLE_4.c.joboffer_id,
        TABLE_4.c.send_4_approval,
    ]
).select_from(join_object).where(
    TABLE_1.c.oferta_id == 3768
)

query_results = connection.execute(select_statement)
```

The output of this SQLAlchemy script is shown below (loaded into a Pandas DataFrame)

[image]

As you can see, the SQLAlchemy instruction neglects those rows where `order = 1,2` and `joboffer_id=Null` and `send_4_approval=Null`.

Is anybody aware of why this happens and how to correct this behaviour? Many thanks

Comment: Your `dbshell` query is using `LEFT JOIN` and your SQLAlchemy is not AFAICT.  See [SQLA Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619353/how-to-perform-a-left-join-in-sqlalchemy#39669377)

Comment: that did the magic! thanks a lot @AdrianKlaver if you paste it in an answer, I can tag it as solved

Comment: By rights I should mark this as a duplicate question, so an answer would be redundant.